# Calculate $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \dfrac{nx}{e \ ^ {nx}}$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, summation

I need to calculate $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \dfrac{nx}{e \ ^ {nx}}$ for $x \ge0 $.

Thanks !

Comment: $k$ doesn't appear in your sum.  Either change it to $n$ or change your $n$'s to $k$'s.

Comment: If your series is accurate then it diverges big time: either those $\;x'$ s are $\;k'$ s, or else change the $\;k\;$ in the series lower limit for an $\;x\;$ .

Comment: In your integrals, are you integrating with respect to $n$ or $x$?

Comment: @JasonM changed it, sorry for that

Comment: @Henry integral with respect o x

Comment: This is $x\sum_{n=1}^\infty nr^n$ with $r=e^{-x}$, and you may want to check out http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/30732.

Comment: But in your sum, $x$ is exogenous  while $n$ goes from $1$ to $\infty$

Comment: @Liad No worries.  Don't forget to put the $dx$ or whichever you meant in your integrals.  And you can't equate the sum and integral.  It's just bounded by it

Comment: @Henry Well you are right, I see my mistake now, thanks. I see from the answers that there is a simpler way to calculate this.

Answer (score 3):

Hint: $$\dfrac{d}{dt} \sum_{n=0}^\infty t^n = \sum_{n=1}^\infty n t^{n-1}$$
for $|t|<1$.

Comment: To use that I need to show that there is uniform convergence on $[0,1] $ ? 
because this sum only converge uniformly on $[a,\infty) $ for $a\gt0 $

Comment: The series in my answer above converge uniformly on $[-1+\epsilon, 1-\epsilon]$ for any $\epsilon > 0$.  Not on $[0,1]$, but you don't need it at $1$.

Answer (score 0):

The RHS of your first inequlity should probably be $ 1\over \exp 1$ rather than $n\over \exp n$. By the way, let $q= \exp -x$, the general term of your series is $xnq^n$, so it converges either if $x=0$ or if $0\leq q <1$, i.e. $x>0$. You probably know that $\sum _{k=1} ^\infty kq^k= {q\over (1-q)^2}$, and $\sum _{k=1}^\infty {kx \over \exp kx}={x \exp -x \over (1-\exp -x)^2}$